# Reuse an existing id if exist in the database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I would like to do the following:

Inserting the CityHistory into the database using JPA.
The first time there is no data, so a new city will be inserted. (IT WORKS FINE)
the (IDENTIFICATION) within the city table is a unique field.

What I want to achieve is when I am inserting the same city again is to reuse the existing field instead of trying to create a new one (identification will be like a city's unique name).

So how can I do that using JPA or Hibernate?

```
@Entity
public class CityHistory extends History implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "KEY_CITY_HISTORY", nullable = false, precision = 19)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CITY_ID", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_CITY_ID"))
    private City cityId;

    @Column(name = "CITY_NAME", nullable = false)
    private String cityName;
}


@Entity
public class City implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "KEY_CITY", nullable = false, precision = 19)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "IDENTIFICATION", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String identification;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MUNICIPALITY_ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_MUNICIPALITY_ID"))
    private Municipality municipalityId;
}
```

**UPDATE**
Here is how I am writing the data to the database,
It's a Spring Batch itemWriter

```
@Component
public class InfoItemWriter implements ItemWriter<Object> {

    @Autowired
    private CityHistoryRepository cityHistoryRepository;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Object> items) throws Exception {

        if (items.size() > 0 && items.get(0) instanceof CityHistory) {
            cityHistoryRepository.saveAll((List<? extends CityHistory>) items);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply search city by name , if it exist , set new field to the fetched entity , and call save repository method , it'll update instead of new insert .

Comment: not. creating a new record may never reuse an existing id, it would defeat the entire concept of the id. If you mean to update an existing record, instead of creating a new one, run an update query, instead of a create

Comment: There can be the same city name but they have different identifications, so I need the search based on the identification. and how to reuse an existing city by adding a new city history, if not exist I want to add it.

Comment: No, I need to add a new record to the city history, the city history contains a city field, the city field needs to be added to the city table if it doesn't exist, or reused if it has the same identification.

Comment: "or reused if it has the same identification", what do you mean by that? are you talking about foreign keys?

Comment: @Stultuske The identification is a unique field within the city table, It's not a foreign key, and it's stored only at the city table.

Comment: Why are you not using 'identification' as the primary key of City (if it is unique)? Is 'id' in City auto-generated (because I don't see @GeneratedValue)?
Also, I don't think you want the cascade on the ManyToOne side, see https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer The Identification is needed information, and I don't want to show it within another table, that is why I don't want to use it as a primary key, also it's String, and I prefer a Long for the primaryKey. Regarding the Id, it's auto-generated.

Comment: @Ali yes, I get that, but you are talking about a table "history of city", not about the table City, so in that table, it's a foreign key

Comment: @Ali either way, you have a CASCADE.PERSIST (implied by ALL) on the child (CityHistory) and Hibernate sees entities with a NULL auto-gen ID as _new_, so it will cascade the persist.
I would get rid of the cascade (the inverse may make sense, e.g., you delete a city and it deltes the CityHistory) and then you have to perform one query per insert to get the city.

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer  Actually it's the opposite, I am creating the CityHistory, and from there the City will be created if it does not exist! That is my intention. So the CityHistory is the parent!

Comment: @Ali that's not the semantic meaning of ManyToOne. Can you have a City without a CityHistory? Yes. Can you have a CityHistory without a City? No -> City is the parent. Compare with: BlogPostComment --ManyToOne--> BlogPost The BlogPost is the parent, it can have multiple or none Comments. The Comment has a connection to its parent Entity.

Comment: Can you have a City without a CityHistory? No. Can you have a CityHistory without a City? No. That's the case I am working on. One city has at least one cityHistory or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all thanks to all who tried to help!

Reading the resources that `@Benjamin Maurer` provided:

> I don't think you want the cascade on the ManyToOne side, see [One-To-Many](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/)

**The most common Parent – Child association consists of a one-to-many and a many-to-one relationship, where the cascade being useful for the one-to-many side only**

As the relation I have is ManyToOne it was really not useful to use the cascade and doesn't serve my need.

I used a different approache to reach the goal. I have created a service where it validates the existence of a city, then adds a new city if it does not exist.

```
@Service
public class CityHistoryServiceImpl implements CityHistoryService {
    @Autowired
    CityRepository cityRepository;
    @Autowired
    CityHistoryRepository cityHistoryRepository;

    @Override
    public Optional<CityHistory> addCityHistory(City city, String cityName, ..) {

        if (city != null && cityName != null) {

            City city1 = addCityIfNotExist(city);

            CityHistory cityHistory = new CityHistory();
            cityHistory.setCityId(city1);
            cityHistory.setCityName(cityName);

            cityHistoryRepository.save(cityHistory);
            return Optional.of(cityHistory);
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    } ....

    private City addCityIfNotExist(City city) {
        City city1 = cityRepository.findFirstByBagId(city.getBagId());
        if (city1 == null) {
            city1 = cityRepository.save(city);
        }
        return city1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate will use the `@Id` property of City to determine if it is new or not. When it is `null`, Hibernate couldn't possibly know that a similar entry already exists.
So you need to perform a query to find each city first:

```
    for (var history : histories) {
        var cities = em.createQuery("select city from City city where city.identification = ?1", City.class)
                        .setParameter(1, history.getCityId().getIdentification())
                        .getResultList();

        if (!cities.isEmpty()) {
            history.setCityId(cities.get(0));
        }

        em.persist(history);
    }
```

If you use Hibernate and `City.identification` is unique and always non-null, you can use it as a [NaturalID](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#naturalid):

In City:

```
@NaturalId
private String identification;
```

Then:

```
    for (var history : histories) {
        var city = em.unwrap(Session.class)
                .byNaturalId(City.class)
                .using("identification", history.getCityId().getIdentification())
                .getReference();

        if (city != null) {
            history.setCityId(city);
        }

        em.persist(history);
    }
```

But if you **do have** `City.id` set, i.e., **not** null, you can use `EntityManager.merge` to get a managed entity:

```
    for (var history : histories) {
        City city = history.getCityId();
        if (city.getId() != null) {
            city = em.merge(city);
            history.setCityId(city);
        }

        em.persist(history);
    }
```

One more remark: We are not in the relational domain, but we are mapping *object graphs*. So calling your fields city**Id** and municipality**Id** is arguably *wrong* - even the type says so: `City cityId`.
They are not just plain identifiers, but full fledged objects: `City city`.